# Cannot mock aem core component with Mockito 3.8

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, aem, junit5

I'm trying to mock a Teaser class (public interface) using mockito core 3.8 and I'm not able to do it.

I've JAVA 11 and this is the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.models.Teaser.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11.0.12+8-LTS-237
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.12+8-LTS-237
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type not found: com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.jackson.ComponentDataModelSerializer
```

What's happening here?

Comment: This is more or less a "ClassNotFound"-exception. This comes from an annotation in the Component-interface. You need also the Adobe AEM's uber-jar in you dependencies.

Comment: @AlexanderBerndt I've included uber-jar dependency with no luck... I don't understand if this is a mockito issue or a wcm core components issue also

Comment: Not sure what this error is about, without a bit of accompanying code and the context of this error... but if you're trying to mock a Sling Model, there's a chance [Sling Mocks](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html#sling-models-1) could be a sensible alternative to Mockito.

Comment: Can you share the minimal code that allows reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got a solution for this.
The problem was that I didn't had wcm core components dependency on my project. Since AEMaaCS includes that dependency as a package, we didn't need to include the dependency in our project.

I ended up adding the dependency but just for the scope=test.